# MS SQL Service Broker - Track queue processing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-broker

I am using **SQL Server 2014**. I have configured the service broker feature in my DB and now processing the Stored Procedure execution requests through it.

Since it executes the Stored Procedure so fast, I am unable to track the progress.

```
Select * 
From sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors

Select  DB_Name(QM.database_id), 
        SQ.[Name], 
        SQ.Activation_Procedure, 
        SQ.is_activation_enabled, 
        QM.* 
From sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors QM
LEFT JOIN sys.service_queues SQ 
    on QM.queue_id = SQ.[object_id]
```

Please suggest, how can I track the execution progress of the messages in the service broker?

I want to save the progress into an auxiliary table & show it to the application. Where can I add the hooks to pull the progress of the message executions?

Comment: To save progress to a table, you'll need to instrument the implementing proc to do that.  As you have found, a polling technique can miss activity.

Comment: But the sProc is meant for the business data only. How can I utilize the sProc to capture the execution progress ?

Comment: In the proc, insert a row into the progress table before you start processing, another row at completion, and perhaps intermediate steps if complex. I can't be much more specific than that given the sketchy information in your question.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way to determine the execution progress at runtime, while Service-broker is executing the sProc.

Comment: You could set up an extended events session to track procedure start and end and use that to track. But what @DanGuzman is suggesting is more transparent and probably easier.